# Draw Orderblock on higher Timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to make an indicator that can plot Orderblocks and other stuff on a higher Timeframe with Boxes.

For example when on the M15 chart I can see H4 Orderblocks. My Code works with the current timeframe, but I cant manage to let it draw on higher Tf.

I used the time function, but I still get errors.

```
indicator('Trade Tools Test', overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500, max_bars_back=1000)

res = input.timeframe(defval="240", options=["60","120","240"], group="Timeframe Selection")
plotOB = input.bool(defval=true, title='Plot OB', group='Order Blocks')
obBullColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.green, 90), title='Bullish OB Color', inline='Set Custom Color', group='Order Blocks')
obBearColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.red, 90), title='Bearish OB Color', inline='Set Custom Color', group='Order Blocks')
obBoxBorder = input.string(defval=line.style_solid, title='OB Box Border Style', options=[line.style_dashed, line.style_dotted, line.style_solid], group='Order Blocks', tooltip='To disable border, set Border Width below to 0')
obBorderTransparency = input.int(defval=80, title='OB Border Box Transparency', minval=0, maxval=100, group='Order Blocks')
obMaxBoxSet = input.int(defval=10, title='Maximum OB Box Displayed', minval=1, maxval=100, group='Order Blocks', tooltip='Minimum = 1, Maximum = 100')
filterMitOB = input.bool(defval=false, title='Custom Color Mitigated OB', group='Order Blocks')
mitOBColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.gray, 90), title='Mitigated OB Color', group='Order Blocks', inline='Set Custom Color Mit OB', tooltip='Set Transparency to 0 to make mitigated OB disappear')


plotLabelOB = input.bool(defval=true, title='Plot OB Label', inline='OB label', group='Label Options')
obLabelColor = input.color(defval=color.gray, title='Color', inline='OB label', group='Label Options')
obLabelSize = input.string(defval=size.tiny, title="Size", options=[size.huge, size.large, size.small, size.tiny, size.auto, size.normal], inline='OB label', group='Label Options')


//Box Types
var int _ob  = 1
var int _fvg = 2
var int _rjb = 3
var int _bos = 4

//Box Labels
var string _obLabel  = "OB"
var string _fvgLabel = "FVG"
var string _rjbLabel = "RJB"
var string _bosLabel = "BoS"
var string _plus     = "+"
var string _minus    = "-"
var string _empty    = ""

//Box Arrays
var box[] _bearBoxesOB  = array.new_box()
var box[] _bullBoxesOB  = array.new_box()
var box[] _bearBoxesFVG = array.new_box()
var box[] _bullBoxesFVG = array.new_box()
var box[] _bearBoxesRJB = array.new_box()
var box[] _bullBoxesRJB = array.new_box()
var box[] _bearBoxesBOS = array.new_box()
var box[] _bullBoxesBOS = array.new_box()

//Functions
isUp(index) =>
    close[index] > open[index]

isDown(index) =>
    close[index] < open[index]

isObUp(index) =>
    isDown(index + 1) and isUp(index) and close[index] > high[index + 1]

isObDown(index) =>
    isUp(index + 1) and isDown(index) and close[index] < low[index + 1]

isFvgUp(index) =>
    (low[index] > high[index + 2])

isFvgDown(index) =>
    (high[index] < low[index + 2])


res = input.timeframe(defval="240", options=["60","120","240"], group="Timeframe Selection")
_htf_High1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, high[1])
_htf_High2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, high[2])
_htf_Low1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, low[1])
_htf_Low2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, low[1])
_htf_BarIndex2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, time[2])

//////////////////// Order Block //////////////////
//Bullish OB Box Plotting
if isObUp(1) and plotOB
    _bullboxOB = box.new(left=_htf_BarIndex2, top=_htf_High2, right=time, bottom=math.min(_htf_Low2, _htf_Low1), border_color=color.new(obBullColor, obBorderTransparency), border_style=obBoxBorder, border_width=1, bgcolor=obBullColor, 
     text=plotLabelOB ? _obLabel  + _plus : _empty, text_halign=text.align_right, text_valign=text.align_bottom, text_size=obLabelSize, text_color=obLabelColor)
    if array.size(_bullBoxesOB) > obMaxBoxSet
        box.delete(array.shift(_bullBoxesOB))
    array.push(_bullBoxesOB, _bullboxOB)

if array.size(_bullBoxesOB) > 0
    for i = array.size(_bullBoxesOB) - 1 to 0 by 1
        _box = array.get(_bullBoxesOB, i)
        _boxLow = box.get_bottom(_box)
        _boxHigh = box.get_top(_box)
        _boxRight = box.get_right(_box)
        if na or (time == _boxRight and not((high > _boxLow and low < _boxLow) or (high > _boxHigh and low < _boxHigh)))
            box.set_right(_box, time + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw something onto another chart, that is not possible.

What you can do is, request data from 4h timeframe and draw that on your chart (M15).

For that, you need to use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. When requesting the bar_index with security() it then gives me an error when drawing, saying „objects placed with xloc.bar_index can only be plotted 500 bars into the future“